# How to determine the block size in training a dataset

Tags: python, transformer-model

I want to build a training dataset by applying a previously trained tokenizer to my text file. The size of my text file is 7.02 GB (7,543,648,706 bytes). This is what I have written:

```
from transformers import LineByLineTextDataset

dataset = LineByLineTextDataset(
    tokenizer=tokenizer,
    file_path="data.txt", block_size = ???
)
```

What does "block size" exactly mean here? How can I determine its value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most implementations of deep learning models cannot process sequential input data of variable lengths (they can if the batch size is 1, however, this is very inefficient and impractical). So, they take inputs of a fixed length.

For example, if an input batch of size 2 is:

```
hello world
my name is stack overflow
```

they should be padded to the max length (e.g., 10) like

```
hello world 0  0     0        0 0 0 0 0
my    name  is stack overflow 0 0 0 0 0
```

Your `dataset` should provide batches of the fixed size and `block_size` is for this purpose. If an input is too long, it will be truncated  to blocks of the same size.

Answer (score 0):

If we look at the [source code](https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/blob/master/src/transformers/data/datasets/language_modeling.py#L118):

```py
batch_encoding = tokenizer(lines, add_special_tokens=True, truncation=True, max_length=block_size)
```

`block_size` is the size at which lines are truncated to ensure they are equi-length.